# ggplot: higher yaxis values added at the bottom in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot different sales trend over date.

The sales trend numbers increases and so the `y axis` added values at the bottom with `facet_grid`. From the main dataset I used `pivot_longer`

```
library(ggplot2)

stc_ov <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18437, 18437, 18437, 18437, 
    18438, 18438, 18438, 18438, 18439, 18439, 18439, 18439, 18440, 
    18440, 18440, 18440, 18441, 18441, 18441, 18441, 18442, 18442, 
    18442, 18442, 18443, 18443, 18443, 18443, 18444, 18444, 18444, 
18444, 18445, 18445, 18445, 18445, 18446, 18446, 18446, 18446, 
18447, 18447, 18447, 18447, 18448, 18448, 18448, 18448, 18449, 
18449, 18449, 18449, 18450, 18450, 18450, 18450, 18451, 18451, 
18451, 18451, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18452, 18453, 18453, 18453, 
18453, 18454, 18454, 18454, 18454, 18455, 18455, 18455, 18455, 
18456, 18456, 18456, 18456, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18457, 18458, 
18458, 18458, 18458, 18459, 18459, 18459, 18459, 18460, 18460, 
18460, 18460), class = "Date"), TypeOfSales = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Sale A Trend", 
"Sale CurC Trend", "Sale D Trend", "Sale ConC Trend"), class = "factor"), 
    Values_Of_Totals = c("174881", "258685", "14476", "448042", 
    "178021", "271697", "14894", "464612", "181340", "285637", 
    "15301", "482278", "195212", "309713", "16095", "521020", 
    "195212", "309713", "16095", "521020", "208121", "334822", 
    "16893", "559836", "213199", "347979", "17400", "578578", 
    "220115", "359860", "17834", "597809", "221408", "379892", 
    "18213", "619513", "230434", "394227", "18655", "643316", 
    "240185", "409083", "19268", "649428", "248374", "424433", 
    "19693", "692500", "254523", "439948", "20160", "714631", 
    "259926", "456831", "20642", "737399", "265404", "476378", 
    "21129", "762911", "272524", "495513", "21604", "789641", 
    "279991", "515386", "22123", "817500", "289234", "534621", 
    "22674", "846529", "299251", "553471", "23174", "875896", 
    "309386", "571460", "23727", "904573", "318316", "592032", 
    "24309", "934657", "329861", "612815", "24915", "967591", 
    "341942", "635757", "25602", "1003301", "358529", "653751", 
    "26273", "1038553")), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want that with increasing of `Values_Of_Totals` on `y axis` should adjust itself and not add the higher values at the bottom.

```
ggplot(stc_ov, aes(x=Date,y = Values_Of_Totals,group=1),
   text = paste('</br> Number of cases: ', Values_Of_Totals,
                '</br> Date: ',strftime(Date, format = "%d-%b-%y"))) + 
 geom_line()+facet_grid(~TypeOfSales)
```

[image: Facet Grid]

1. I tried adding `ylim(c(1,1000000))` but it also didn't work. This resulted in range too higher so that trend was not visible
2. `scale_y_discrete()` also didn't work
3. I tried

   ```
   ggplot(stc_ov, aes(x=Date,y = Values_Of_Totals,group=1),
   text = paste('</br> Number of cases: ', Values_Of_Totals,
                '</br> Date: ',strftime(Date, format = "%d-%b-%y"))) + 
   geom_line(aes(color = TypeOfSales))
   ```

It gave saw tooth line graph

[image: Without Facet Grid]

Could anyone help me in points 1 & 3 what I am missing here?

Comment: datewise_totals_wo_State is a bigger dataframe with all the type of sales in different columns. The final dataframe is stc_ov on which I have to work

Comment: I have added the dataframe for datewise_totals_wo_State

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointing to @Limey solution you should try:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Date,y=as.numeric(Values_Of_Totals),color=TypeOfSales,group=TypeOfSales))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Values_Of_Totals` is a `character`.  Convert them to numerics (`Values_Of_Totals=as.numeric(Values_Of_Totals)`) and your problem will be solved.

Comment: will this also solve the dynamic y axis problem as well? In Oreilly book i found why it was showing sawtooth pattern - 
If any discrete variables are mapped to aesthetics like colour or linetype, they are automatically used as grouping variables.
so I was changing the grouping with different combination but was not able to

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset has `stc_ov$Values_Of_Totals` as a character vector, and not a continuous numeric vector.  This is why your y axis has all the numbers indicated on the y axis and why they are not necessarily in order.

This fixes it:

```
stc_ov$Values_Of_Totals <- as.numeric(stc_ov$Values_Of_Totals)
```

Also, you may want to set `scales="free_y"` and use `facet_wrap()` in order to clearly see the trends for your `TypeOfScales`:

```
ggplot(stc_ov, aes(x=Date,y = Values_Of_Totals,group=1),
       text = paste('</br> Number of cases: ', Values_Of_Totals,
                    '</br> Date: ',strftime(Date, format = "%d-%b-%y"))) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = TypeOfSales)) +
  facet_wrap(~TypeOfSales, scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]